# angular/javascript html input type 'time' shows wrong time on submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, date, time

Im facing a strange issue.

In my form i use 2 inputs with type "time":

```
<div style="float:left;width:50%;">
  <div style="background:#efefef;!important;line-height:30px;font-size:14px;text-transform: uppercase;text-align:center;border:none">
     Start time
     <input type="time" name="start_time" formatted-time ng-model="editFields.disable_freelance_start_time" style="width:100%;border:1px solid #ccc;border-right:none;margin-bottom:10px;padding:5px;" />
  </div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:50%">
  <div style="background:#efefef;!important;line-height:30px;font-size:14px;text-transform: uppercase;text-align:center;border:none;border-left:2px solid #ccc">
   End time
   <input type="time" name="end_time" formatted-time  ng-model="editFields.disable_freelance_end_time" style="width:100%;border:1px solid #ccc;border-left:none;margin-bottom:10px;padding:5px;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

and in my controller i set my model:

```
    $scope.editFields.disable_freelance_start_time = new Date();
    $scope.editFields.disable_freelance_end_time = new Date();
```

and in the view it shows the right time in the input - the current time (see screenshot) [image]

but when i "submit the form" and inspect the object it shows wrong values - the times are 2 hours off.. (i live in Amsterdam, maybe something with daylight savings?)

it shows this:

```
[start_time] => 2016-05-17T01:21:56.382Z
[end_time] => 2016-05-17T01:21:56.382Z
```

so it show 1:21 but now is 03:21 -- why is this happening and how can i fix this?

Comment: its normal, get TimeZoneOffset, which is in minutes, and you can manually calc with that.

Comment: Note the timezone is Z, or GMT. Amsterdam is GMT+0200 and `2016-05-17T01:21:56.382Z` is an identical instant in time to `2016-05-17T03:21:56.382+0200`.

Comment: i understand, but i send this to my php backend, where i get this as a string. Should i process this then in php?

Comment: could you provide the formattedTime directive code?
You try to store Date object which is mean coming from clients browser

Answer (score 1):

The input selection boxes will be in the browser's current local timezone. On submit, it converts it to UTC. This is usually handled by just accepting and storing UTC times on the server and in the database.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you have problem with timezone. That problem also had me. I have solved it with Mooment.js.
My solution use Mooment.js http://momentjs.com/

Comment: An answer should not require a library that is not in the question or tagged. Also, an answer should actually contain an answer, not a suggestion to use a library.

Comment: @RobG. Thanks ill add example